Why is my application reading outdated JSON settings and class library changes in Visual Studio?
I'm relatively new to C# and Visual Studio, so I appreciate any guidance.
I have a solution with multiple projects, including:

A WPF project
An ASP.NET project
Several Class Library projects
Several WPF Class Library projects

Additionally, I have a JSON file in the solution that stores settings used across the projects.
The Problem:
I updated the value of a setting in the JSON file, specifically the "server" setting from "localhost" to a new value. However, when I run the application, even in debug mode, it continues to read the old value "localhost".
I’ve also encountered a similar issue with one of the Class Library projects that defines and implements an interface. I made changes to the interface and its implementation, but when the application loads, it seems to use an outdated version of the Class Library. This causes the application to crash, stating that the implementation no longer supports the interface correctly.
What I've Tried

Performed "Clean Solution" followed by "Rebuild Solution".

Deleted all files in:
C:\Users<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_ae12b280\Designer\Cache\

Verified there are no old versions of the JSON file or the Class Library in the solution directory.


Code Example
For context, here’s the code I use to validate and load the Class Library that implements the interface:
    var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(pluginsPath + plugin_.Filename);

    var types = assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(t => typeof(IPlugin).IsAssignableFrom(t) && !t.IsInterface && !t.IsAbstract);

    foreach (var type in types)
    {
        // The application does not enter this loop
    }

Question:
What steps can I take to ensure that the application reads the updated JSON file and uses the correct version of the Class Library? Could this be a caching issue, or is there something I'm missing in my build process?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Version the DLL to confirm or install the tool ILSpy, drag and drop your DLL in and check its got the files and code expected for that version, I suspect you've got cached DLLs.

Thank you @JeremyThompson for your answer, I literally deleted all the files on my computer with that specific DLL name, and then simply rebuilt the project. And also, what about the JSON file? How come it reads an old value?

OK run Process Monitor, turn off Registry, Process and Network so only File System is being recorded. Clear ProcessMonitor, then quickly start recording, build your code then quickly stop recording. Then see where Visual Studio is looking for the JSON file? Assuming the JSON file is not an embedded resource which it doesn't sound like it is.

If your application reads an old json, then there must somehow still be this old json. Reassure, that you really understand where the file comes from.

Moreover, if I remember correctly, a rebuild only removes dlls that will be rebuild. If you renamed a project, the old dll "survives" a rebuild. I would delete the release and debug folders
